# Problemas para cirar comando SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Olá, pessoal. Estou criando um projeto que manipula cadastro de usuários. Neste projeto existirão vários tipos de usuários. Para simplificar, vamos chamar os tipos de 1,2 e 3. Dependendo do tipo de usuário, são alteradas as telas e recursos que ele consegue acessar.

Para começar, tenho que explicar sobre a estrutura de tabelas do meu banco de dados. No meu banco eu tenho uma tabela que se chama "usuario" onde se armazena os dados do usuário(nome, cpf, rg, etc....) e uma tabela que se chama "grupo" que armazena os tipos de grupos 1, 2, 3 e a descrição dos grupos. E depois, tem uma tabela que se chama "usuario_grupo" que associa a tabela "usuario" e "grupo".

O assunto que estou tratando é o seguinte: quando é cadastrado um usuário novo, eu estou tentando inserir na tabela "usuario_grupo" um registro novo que associe o id do usuário e o id do grupo deste usuário. Mas estou com dificuldades para montar o código sql. Quando executo o código aparece o erro:

**unexpected token: values**

Estou enviando os arquivos principais que tratam do cadastro de usuário.

**CadastroUsuarioBean.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private UsuariosRep usuariosRep;

@Inject
private EstadosRep estadosRep;

@Inject
private CidadeRep cidadeRep;

@Inject
private CadastroUsuarioService cadastroUsuarioService;

private Usuario usuario;

private Estado categoriaPai;

private Estado estado;

private Cidade cidade;

private String email;

private List<SelectItem> listEstados;

private List<SelectItem> listCidades;


public CadastroUsuarioBean() {
    limpar();
}

public boolean isEditando() {
    boolean resultado = false;
    if (this.usuario != null) {
        resultado = usuario.getId() != null;
    }
    return resultado;
}


public void inicializar() {
    listEstados = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    List<Estado> estados = estadosRep.raizes();

    for (Estado e : estados) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(e.getEstado_sigla());
        item.setValue(e);
        listEstados.add(item);
    }

    if(!isEditando())
    {
        usuario.setStatus("Ativo");
    }

    if (this.estado != null) {
        estados = estadosRep.raizes();
    }
}

public void limpar() {
    usuario = new Usuario();
    listEstados = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
}

public void salvar() {
    if (usuariosRep.porCpf(this.usuario.getCpf()) != null){
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Este CPF já existe!");
    }
    else{   
        usuariosRep.InserirTabelaUsuarioGrupo(this.usuario.getId());
        this.usuario = cadastroUsuarioService.salvar(this.usuario);
        limpar();
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Cadastro de usuário efetuado com sucesso!");
    }
}

public void carregarCidades(){
    listCidades = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    List<Cidade> cidades = cidadeRep.cidadesDe(usuario.getEstado());
    for (Cidade c : cidades) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(c.getCidadeNome());
        item.setValue(c);
        listCidades.add(item);
    }
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Estado getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListEstados() {
    return listEstados;
}

public void setListEstados(List<SelectItem> listEstados) {
    this.listEstados = listEstados;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String register() {
    return "thanks?faces-redirect=true";
}

public Estado getCategoriaPai() {
    return categoriaPai;
}

public void setCategoriaPai(Estado categoriaPai) {
    this.categoriaPai = categoriaPai;
}

public Cidade getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListCidades() {
    return listCidades;
}

public void setListCidades(List<SelectItem> listCidades) {
    this.listCidades = listCidades;
}

public UsuariosRep getUsuariosRep() {
    return usuariosRep;
}

public void setUsuariosRep(UsuariosRep usuariosRep) {
    this.usuariosRep = usuariosRep;
}   


}
```

**CadastroUsuarioService.java**

```
public class CadastroUsuarioService implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private UsuariosRep usuarios;

public Usuario salvar(Usuario usuario) {
    return usuarios.guardar(usuario);
}

@Transactional
public void excluir(Usuario usuario) throws NegocioException {
    usuario = this.usuarios.porNome(usuario.getNome());
    this.usuarios.remover(usuario);
}
}
```

**UsuariosRep.java**

```
public class UsuariosRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Usuario guardar(Usuario usuario) {

    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    usuario = manager.merge(usuario);
    trx.commit();
    return usuario;
}

public Usuario porCpf(String cpf){
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
        usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where cpf = :cpf", Usuario.class)
                .setParameter("cpf", cpf).getSingleResult();
    }catch (NoResultException e){
        // Nenhum usuario encontrado com o nome informado.
    }
    return usuario;
}

public Usuario porNome(String nome) {
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
    usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where lower(nome) = :nome", Usuario.class)
            .setParameter("nome", nome.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    }catch (NoResultException e){
        // Nenhum usuario encontrado com o nome informado.
    }
    return usuario;
}

public void InserirTabelaUsuarioGrupo(Long id){
    Usuario usuario = null;
    usuario = (Usuario) this.manager.createQuery("Insert into usuario_grupo(usuario_id,grupo_id) values(id,1)");
}

public Usuario porId(Long id)
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, id);
}

public List<Usuario> listaDeUsu() 
{
    return manager.createQuery("from Usuario", Usuario.class).getResultList();
}

public List<Usuario> raizes()
{
    return  manager.createQuery("from Usuario",Usuario.class).getResultList(); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Usuario> filtrados(UsuarioFilter filtro) {

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

    if (filtro.getNome() != "") 
    {
        System.out.println(filtro.getNome());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nome", filtro.getNome()));
    }

    if (filtro.getStatus() != null)
    {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", filtro.getStatus()));
    }

    // orderBy do SQL
    return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id")).list();
}

public void remover(Usuario usuario) {
    this.manager.remove(usuario);
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    manager.flush();
    trx.commit();
}

public Usuario porEmail(String email) {
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
        usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where lower(email) = :email", Usuario.class)
                .setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (NoResultException e){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Nenhum usuário encontrado");
    }
    return usuario;
}
}
```

Entre os códigos, no UsuariosRep.java vocês encontrarão um método chamado InserirTabelaUsuarioGrupo. Este é o método que estou usando para inserir um registro novo na tabela "usuario_grupo". E no CadastroUsuarioBean.java, no método "salvar" está sendo chamado o método InserirTabelaUsuarioGrupo.

No InserirTabelaUsuarioGrupo vocês verão que estou inserindo 1 como o id do grupo. Estou inserindo 1 somente para fins de teste. Após resolver este erro, pretendo inserir dinamicamente.

Agradeço qualquer conselho ou opinião.

Comment: Você quer oque afinal?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que você está confundindo a linguagem do JPA/Hibernate (JPQL ou HQL) com SQL de verdade.

Dei uma conferida aqui https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2800 e a HQL tem o comando INSERT mas ele não usa a palavra VALUES, enquanto que a JPQL nem tem INSERT, tem apenas a chamada em.persist() em Java (eu nem sabia disso, conhecia só o INSERT do SQL normal mesmo e achei que fosse igual em JPQL).

Além do mais, lembre-se que a JPQL/HQL trabalha com os nomes de classes e atributos como declarados em Java, que podem ser diferentes dos nomes das tabelas e colunas (é possível que nem exista uma entidade usuario_grupo do ponto de vista do JPQL/HQL, dependendo de como você fez o mapeamento objeto-relacional).

Eu sugeriria trocar o createQuery por um createNativeQuery no seu INSERT que usa SQL de verdade. E não esqueça de um .executeUpdate() no final. O executeUpdate é usado tanto para updates quanto para inserts. Deve funcionar, ou pelo menos mudar a mensagem de erro para te colocar na direção certa :-)

Answer (score 0):

Olha só, se você quer inserir o usuário junto do seu relacionamento com o grupo é só explorar o JPA e Hibernate, não precisa usar SQL. Você faria da seguinte forma:

1 - Adicionar mapeamento de usuário e grupo na entidade criada. Foi utilizado o CASCADE ALL para que a inserção/atualização/deleção do registro do usuário afete o registro de relacionamento em UsuarioGrupo.

```
Class Usuario {
     //Todos os atributos do usuário
     //Relacionamento entre usuário e grupo
     //
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<UsuarioGrupo> usuarioGrupo;
}
```

2 - Na persistência do registro, é só chamar o persist do JPA:

```
//JPA
public void inserirUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
   manager.getTransaction().begin();
   manager.persist(usuario);
   manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Quando o persist for chamado, será criado tanto o registro de usuário como seu relacionamento na tabela UsuarioGrupo desde que você tenha preenchido a entidade Usuario com essas informações antes de chamar o método inserirUsuario. Isso vai acontecer porque você utilizou o CASCADE para facilitar o trabalho! Usando JPA você não vai precisar utilizar SQL em lugar algum, e nem é recomendado pois a abstração do JPQL permite mudar de banco sem alterar NADA no código de negócio! Espero ter ajudado ^^

OBS: Mantenha o nome dos métodos com a primeira letra em caixa baixa, seguindo os padrões de nomenclatura do Java (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).